# Invoke method with optional arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to invoke a method based on it's name with some optional arguments:

```
var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("Foo", 
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var queryString = _httpContext.Request.QueryString;
var somethingElse = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3 };
var args = new object[]{ queryString, somethingElse  };

if(methodInfo != null)
    methodInfo.Invoke(this, args);


private void Foo(object[] args)
{
    foreach(var item in args)
       //...
}
```

If I only pass the `queryString` to `args` I get the following error:

> *Object of type 'System.Web.HttpValueCollection' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.*

How is the `object[] parameters` arguments in `methodInfo.Invoke()` intented to be used?

Comment: `if(methodInfo == null) methodInfo.Invoke(this, args);` this code will never work...

Comment: which line threw this error ?

Comment: @Knaģis `!=`, sorry wrote it on top of my head

Comment: I find it highly interesting that it tries to "call" the method before counting the arguments, I did not know that :) I thought you'd get something like `WrongNumberOfArgumentException` or something. (And as both @Knaģis and @Alessandro points out, you've misunderstood how to pass multiple arguments to the invoke method.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { args });
```

The parameter is only 1 and is an array of object. If you pass `args` it consider multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since your method takes a single parameter of type `object[]` you need to pass that parameter as an array inside another array.

```
// this is what is passed to your method as the first parameter
var args = new object[]{ queryString, somethingElse  };

// the .Invoke method expects an array of parameters...
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { args });
```

If your method would be `void Foo(string a, List<int> b)` etc. then the Invoke would be called like

```
// the .Invoke method expects an array of parameters...
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { queryString, somethingElse });
```